# What is good practise to output data with double quotes " in php?

Tags: php, html, escaping

I have some html text and want to put it into a variable.

Note: I can't use `?> .... <?` here, I need html in variable.

The problem is about quotes symbol — `"`. I want my html will be with `"`, not with `'`, so I can't use this:

```
$var = "some 'name'";
```

I can't use next code, because I want to use interpolation:

```
$var = 'name is "$name"'; // this code doesn't work. output is: name is "$name".
```

To achieve, what I want, I can use this:

```
$var = "some \"$name\"";
```

This works, but it is stupid, especially with a bit larger amount of html text, like in this:

```
$results['main'] .= '
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="/clients/add/" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-lg" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Добавить клиента</a>
        </div>
    </div>
';
```

I need to escape 12 `"` symbols in example. It is not good at all.

Comment: Have you tried HEREDOC?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply break the variable string like this:

```
$results['main'] .= '
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="/clients/add/" class="btn" role="button">'.$name.'</a>
    </div>
</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PHP HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)
You can declare your variables before the start of the HEREDOC and then use them in the doc without worrying about double quotes, etc. Since I do not see your vars in the html example you provided. I have made up an example.

```
$url = "<a href = 'http://google.com'>Google </a>";

$results['main'] .= <<<EOF
Here is a good website: $url. I hope you enjoy it
EOF;
```

Comment: Lot of syntax errors in code... You cannot use " quotes in multiple times without use .(dot) $url = "<a href = "http://google.com"> </Google>"; this will trhows error, in href declaration use backslashes or simple quotes.

Comment: Nice suggestion. But it will work only if there are no spaces before final `EOF` pointer. What if I have some tabs (due to follow code format)

Comment: @Kamil. Read up on HEREDOC. No errors will be thrown.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav just don't add these tabs for this line. As simple as that.

Comment: The only rule on a HEREDOC is that the final closing tag can not be indented, It doesn't really care what comes between the tags.

Comment: @Len_D I meant this situation: http://i.gyazo.com/88f0716ffec87fc8c347639940f355c0.png . How to make this work? It will broke code format, if I will this: http://i.gyazo.com/6be80c6e6dd93623f7b6deab133f97ad.png

Comment: @Len_D are you sure ? .. It will throws: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 1, you cannot pass more same quotes into variable declaration.... without backslashes or join the string with dot.

Comment: @Kamil. You're right. My brain was disengaged :-(
Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav if you are so much scared with such a drastic code indentation breakage - then don't use this method. Your phobia is quite unique though: thousands of developers are using heredoc with no problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you want print `"` use entities: `&quote;`

And all quotes in string you can replace with str_replace like this:

```
$myString = '';
foreach($someArrayWithStrings as $string) {
   $myString .= str_replace("\"","&quot",$string);
}
```

http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html

Comment: His task is to get $someArrayWithStrings, not to format it.

Comment: No mate, you're wrong, he ask for how can he write some another variable into another one variable. He have problem with quotes. If he will change the quotes to entities, it will be work, and at the print will be change the entities back to quotes...

Comment: Mate i think that i understant how PHP works as well... i programming more than 7 years. He don't need convert it into entities, he just need use "." (dot) to pass variable. But he have problem with quotes. So he can use backslashes or entities ... But in any case, is wrong passing HTML into variables.

Comment: One don't need neither backslashes nor entities to simply put one variable into string in PHP.

Comment: I'm not talking about putting wariable into another. Ofcourse that don't need backslashes and entities to pass variables into another vars. But he wants use HTML code with this quotes " and he have problem with parsing it, so the solution how can parse it without change quotes in HTML is backslashes or entities. Look at his question : To achieve, what I want, I can use this:

$var = "some \"$name\"";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55671/discussion-between-your-common-sense-and-kamil).

Comment: PHP doesn't parse any quotes in variables.  So, there is not a single problem with it. Learn PHP. It seems you are confusing PHP with HTML.

Comment: I think that you need Learn how php work. If you will try this: $myVar = "My text "$variableWithTextWichIWantQuote" another text"; It will throws you syntax error. That is for what he asking about. So it seems that you're cunfused .... Or maybe just we do not understand each other ...

Comment: Your code won't help with it. Your code has absolutely nothing to do with this problem. You just cannot tell inline PHP strings from string contents. Learn PHP.

Comment: I don't need learn PHP... i just understand his question as that he needs put's quotes between variable which he want's to put into another variable like here.. $var = "some \"$name\""; So if you don't understand what i mean, go and you learn PHP how it works... Bye. We spending our time with nothing .... i think that you just don't understant me and i you. Or i just maybe bad understand the question...